# Mean of frequency table / grouped data

Tags: statistics

Thanks for reading my question.  I am wondering about the mean of a frequency table.  The table is as follows:

[image: ft]

So do how would I write out the midpoint and find the mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a cumulative frequency table, which means it lists frequencies in the format $< 150$, instead of the usual $140-150$ format in a frequency distribution. We first need to convert the table into the latter format:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Frequency} \\ \hline
140 \text{ to }150 & 12 - 0 = 12 \\ \hline
150 \text{ to }160 & 34 - 12 = 22 \\ \hline
160 \text{ to }170 & 64 - 34 = 30 \\
\end{array}
$$

And now we can use the standard method for finding the mean:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Frequency $f$} & \textbf{Midpoint $x$} & \mathbf{fx} \\ \hline
140 \text{ to }150 & 12 & 145 & 1740 \\ \hline
150 \text{ to }160 & 22 & 155 & 3410 \\ \hline
160 \text{ to }170 & 30 & 165 & 4950 \\ \hline
& \sum f = 64 & & \sum fx = 10100
\end{array}
$$

So the mean is $\frac{\sum fx}{\sum f} = 10100/64 = 157.8125 \text{ cm}$. As you can see, cumulative frequency tables are not very convenient for finding the mean, but they are useful for calculating the median, the quartiles, percentile ranks, etc. by plotting an [ogive](http://www.everythingmaths.co.za/maths/grade-11/11-statistics/11-statistics-03.cnxmlplus).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have a question though.  With the frequency, why is it MINUS the other frequency.  eg, why 34-12?  Thanks

Comment: 12 people are shorter than 150 cm, and 34 people are shorter than 160 cm. Those 34 people include the 12 who are shorter than 150 cm, but we don't want to count those in the interval 150 to 160. So we subtract them.

Comment: i really appreciate your help but don't want to be a nuisance.  How would we calculate the Standard Deviation from this?

Comment: [This](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52199.html) and [this](http://www.lboro.ac.uk/media/wwwlboroacuk/content/mlsc/downloads/var_stand_deviat_group.pdf) are good explanations for calculating standard deviation from a frequency table.